# Rspec: define tests group as method that takes arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Say, I have a test like that:

```
  describe "signin" do
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "with invalid data" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_error_message("Invalid") }
      it { should_not have_link("Sign out") }
      it "should redirect to same page" do
        current_path.should == root_path
      end
    end

  end
```

And I want the same test to be performed in any another page too (not `root_path`) : it should be redirected to the same page.

So, I want to keep it DRY, and therefore to declare this test in one place, and call it with different arguments: firstly with `root_path`, and then with some other page.

I know we can define custom matchers in `support/utilities.rb`, but how can we define tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want this same code to be executed, but with varying values for what is currently `root_path` (i.e you would visit some other path and redirect to that other path in the case of invalid data being entered).

In that case, you'll want to [provide context to a shared example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block)

```
shared_examples_for "visit and click sign in" do
  before do
    visit path
    click_button "Sign in"
  end
  it { should have_error_message("Invalid") }
  it { should_not have_link("Sign out") }
  it "should redirect to same page" do
    current_path.should == path
  end
end

describe "root signin" do
  it_behaves_like "visit and click sign in" do
    let(:path) {root_path}
  end
end
```

You can't just pass in `root_path` because the arguments to `shared_examples` get evaluated in the context of RSpec, not the "test environment".

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Shared example group](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group). E.g.

```
shared_examples_for "redirect and show error" do
  it { should have_error_message("Invalid") }
  it { should_not have_link("Sign out") }
  it "should redirect to same page" do
    current_path.should == root_path
  end
end

describe "signin" do
  before { visit root_path }

  describe "with invalid data" do
    before { click_button "Sign in" }
    it_behaves_like "redirect and show error"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `custom example groups`:

http://benediktdeicke.com/2013/01/custom-rspec-example-groups/